Erroneous "One or more validation errors occurred." thrown by .net 8 api
Here is my request payload:
{
  "branchDeposit": {
    "id": 0,
    "createdDate": "2024-12-30T23:42:33.917Z",
    "depositedDate": "2024-12-30T23:42:33.917Z",
    "branchId": 69,
    "bagSerialNumber": "FAKE1234",
    "teamMemberId": 20059,
    "dollarOne": 1216,
    "dollarTwo": 232,
    "dollarFive": 5690,
    "dollarTen": 15580,
    "dollarTwenty": 27660,
    "dollarFifty": 45450,
    "dollarHundred": 96900,
    "dollarMutilated": 0,
    "dollarTotal": 192728,
    "coinPenny": 10.28,
    "coinNickel": 25.25,
    "coinDime": 30.3,
    "coinQuarter": 32.75,
    "coinHalfDollar": 64.5,
    "coinDollar": 120,
    "coinTotal": 283.08,
    "depositTotal": 193011.08,
    "currencyType": "FIT"
  }
}

As you can see bagSerialNumber and currencyType are included.
Here are the relevant definitions from BranchDeposit.cs:
        [Required, JsonPropertyName("bagSerialNumber")]
        public string BagSerialNumber { get; set; }
        [Required, JsonPropertyName("currencyType")]
        public string CurrencyType { get; set; }

As you can these properties are json properties and should except 'bagSerialNumber' and 'currencyType'.
Here is my erroneous error:
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc9110#section-15.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "errors": {
        "CurrencyType": [
            "The CurrencyType field is required."
        ],
        "BagSerialNumber": [
            "The BagSerialNumber field is required."
        ]
    },
    "traceId": "8000000d-000c-fb00-b63f-84710c7967bb"
}

Why am I receiving this erroneous error?
As requested here is the code from the controller method.  I've set breakpoints here but it isn't even being reached.  I suspect the issue has to do with receiving and deserializing the request:
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult<Result> Post([FromBody] BranchDeposit branchDeposit)
        {
            try
            {
                ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(branchDeposit, nameof(branchDeposit));
                ArgumentOutOfRangeException.ThrowIfGreaterThan(branchDeposit.Id, 0, nameof(branchDeposit.Id));
                var result = _service.InsertBranchDeposit(branchDeposit);
                if (result == 0)
                {
                    return StatusCode(
                        (int)HttpStatusCode.Created, 
                        new Result
                        {
                            IsSuccess = true,
                            Message = "Branch Deposit inserted successfully",
                            Payload = new { result }
                        });
                }
                else
                {
                    return BadRequest(new Result
                    {
                        IsSuccess = false,
                        Message = string.Format("Branch Deposit not inserted due to SQL Error Code: {0}", result),
                        Payload = new { result }
                    });
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, ex.Message);
                return StatusCode(500, new Result
                {
                    IsSuccess = false,
                    Message = string.Format("Branch Deposit not inserted due to the following Exception: {0}", ex.Message),
                    Payload = new { exception = ex.Message }
                });
            }
        }

In Program.cs here is where I set the json options:

builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(x =>
{
    x.JsonSerializerOptions.AllowTrailingCommas = true;
    x.JsonSerializerOptions.IncludeFields = false;
    x.JsonSerializerOptions.IgnoreReadOnlyProperties = false;
    x.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;
    x.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles;
});


Post the method signature for your controller method

I ran it by copilot: It looks like the issue is that your JSON payload is nested under a branchDeposit object, but your controller method expects the BranchDeposit object directly. This discrepancy is causing the deserialization to fail, resulting in the validation errors.  It's working now
